# Model returning null values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm a new bee to web development. I need to get data (some columns) from the `job` table and filter it according to the user name in the session and a status value (status is a TINYINT there for contains 0 and 1).

Here is my model:

```
public function show_work() {
      $user_name = $this->session->userdata('Name');
      $this->load->database();
      $this->db->select('jbStageID, Description, StartDate, SpecialDetails, EstimateTime, Instrauctions');
      $this->db->where('Name',$user_name);
      $this->db->where('status','0');
      $rset=$this->db->get('job');
      $result=$rset->result_array();
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function employees()
{
    $this->load->model('show_details');  
    $result= $this->show_details->show_work();
    $data = array();
    $data['inbox'] = $this->show_details->show_work();
    var_dump($result);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
```

}

The issue is I don't get values from the database but value null with empty array. 
The result is like this:

```
Array(
    [inbox] =>
)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. While waiting for answers you should take some time to review our help to know [what you should do when someone answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: "I manage to figure it out, thanks for you help"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the **return** to return the data as below in the model's last line:

```
$result=$rset->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: your answer works but there are two arrays passing values. What`s wrong with my controller

Comment: @user2667314 what output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

you missed $this->db->from

that means from table in sql query.

Comment: There is no need to use `$this->db->from()` if you state the table name in the `$this->db->get()`.